# Very basic question about a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I've recently been trying to get a handle on Lambda expressions and use them more.  I see some examples and I understand what's going on, like this ...

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda = num => num < 5;
```

But then I see this example and it looks so .... simple, but I don't understand how the lambda expression does anything.  It obviously does, because it sorts, but I don't know how.  `g => g`?  To me this is `g` as the arg, and `g` is also the expresion.  How is this any different from `g;`

```
static void Main()
{            
    int[] ints = { 10, 45, 15, 39, 21, 26 };
    var result = ints.OrderBy(g => g);

    foreach (var i in result)
    {
        System.Console.Write(i + " ");
    }           
}        

// Output: 10 15 21 26 39 45
```

Comment: `g` in the code above represents an item in the collection you're iterating over. It might be more readable as: `var result = ints.OrderBy(item => item);`

Comment: `OrderBy` needs to know how to order. In this case, you order each element by using the default comparer of an `int`. If the array was objects, then it could be `g => g.name` where `name` is a string (and it would order by the `name` property of each object).

Comment: But it also accepts lambdas such as `g => g > 10`, which looks like a `bool`, and it seems not to change anything. I'd like an explanation too.

Comment: `g => g` is basically `g => { return g; }`  It's just short hand so you only need to specify the value to return.  When used in `OrderBy` it's getting the value to order on, which is the `int` in the array.

Comment: You could also do something like `var result = ints.OrderBy(g => g % 5);`, which would give a different result since now we're ordering by the remainder of the item divided by `5`.

Comment: @StackLloyd if you use `OrderBy(g => g > 10)` then it's ordering the items by the result of the comparison only.  So any ints that are greater than 10 will be ordered together but will retain the original order with each other.

Comment: @juharr *So any ints that are greater than 10 will be ordered together but will retain the original order with each other.* Sorry, I don't get it. If I run that on the OP's code, the order doesn't change at all.

Comment: @StackLloyd That's because the only int that returns false in 10 so it comes first, then all the ints that result in true come after it, but will just be in the same order as they currently are since all of them are greater than 10.  If you do `g => g > 20` you'll get 10, 15, 45, 39, 21, 26.  Note all the ints under 20 come first then the ones over, but they are still in the order they were in the original array.

Comment: Ok, so it orders only the numbers which meet that condition, then puts the others in their original order after the sorted ones?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think it was more of a case of me not fully understanding what OrderBy was doing under the hood.  So I did understand the expression, just not how OrderBy was using it.  Thanks for all the help.